# Selenium tooltip text verification

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to verify the tool tip text using selenium for the following HTML code.But not sure how to proceed further.

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="divImgAnnualAllowanceType" class="imgHelp" _tooltip="If the client 
    <br>an  arrangement
    <br>a durable arrangement 
    <br>received a Lump Sum.">
</div>
```

Since the text is separated by `<br>` I don't know how to retrieve this text.
I tried using the following code but got null value.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("divImgAnnualAllowanceType")).getAttribute("value");
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use proper attribute name with `getAttribute()` method and there is no attribute as value in your targeted `<div>` element, you can try below code:

```
String tooltip = driver.findElement(By.id("divImgAnnualAllowanceType")).getAttribute("_tooltip");
System.out.println(tooltip.replace("<br>", ""));
```

In above code, we are storing the tooltip value in a variable then printing the same after replacing all `<br>`.

> This code is written in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the help.This step is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` tags doesn't (necessarily) has `value` attribute, use `getText()` instead

```
driver.findElement(By.id("divImgAnnualAllowanceType")).getText();
```

Comment: i tried using getText() but it didnt fetch me the  text inside the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the attribute which value you need.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("divImgAnnualAllowanceType")).getAttribute("_tooltip");
```